# Can GoogleDocs be used as a csv file viewer?

Tags: google-drive

Suppose that, while browsing, one comes across a hyperlink to a CSV file.  Clicking on it should bring up a Save-File dialog, to download the file.  I often proceed to upload the file to my GoogleDocs account, for viewing.

Is there a way (preferably browser-independent) to skip the download step, and somehow send the CSV file *directly* to my GoogleDocs account?  I'm thinking of some "magic URL" that encodes within it the URL of the desired CSV document, and has the effect of uploading it to my GoogleDocs account *as a spreadsheet* (rather than, e.g., a text file).

PS: No Zoho, please; don't like it.

Comment: I realize this may not be helpful, but if you install the Google Drive desktop client and download the csv file into your local Google Drive folder, it will automatically be uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a way, using the [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer), by following these steps:

- Paste your CSV link
- Click on Generate link
- Open generated link
- Click on Save in Google Docs (Even if there is no preview)
- Go to your document list
- Select the last imported one
- File > Export to Google spreadsheet (if it's not already a spreadsheet)

Maybe it's easier in the and to download and drag & drop the file to the doc list, but your question is without downloading and I think that will do the trick :)

Comment: Google Docs viewer (`https://docs.google.com/viewer?...`) was retired. See the reference on my [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101753/88163) to another question about Google Docs Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Docs, you can only Upload the files saved in your computer.

The feature you are referring to is called as "Remote URL Upload" - which is available in some of the file hosting services but not present in Google Docs at all. This is as a measure to prevent uploading of copy-right protected content.

Apart from that, you will be able to see the .csv file without uploading it to Google Docs, if you have received it as an attachment in an e-mail at your GMail Address.

Comment: There is an extension that allow to upload hosted files to Google Drive directly. See my [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115271/88163)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't "browser independent" but it's very handy: [Save to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne) Google Chrome extension.

But if you still want something browser independent, "we" could create a bookmarklet to call a web app or Google Apps Script that uses the Google Drive API or the Google Apps Script Drive service.

For now I will keep using the referred Chrome extension.